# how to access different tables from the same database simultaneously

Tags: sqlite, qt5, qsqlquery

I am using Qt5 and Sqlite3. I am making a log function. I have two tables, allBooks defined like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS allBooks (NAME VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE, AUTHOR VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, UID VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE, QUANTITY INT NOT NULL);
```

and log which is defined as:
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log (STUDENT VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, UID VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, ISSUED CHAR(11) NOT NULL, RETURNED CHAR(11) NOT NULL);`

The constructor of my log dialog which shows log in a list view is shown below:

```
model = new QStringListModel(this);

QStringList list;

QSqlQuery query1, query2;

query1.exec("SELECT * FROM log");

while(query1.next())
{
    QSqlRecord rec = query1.record();

    QString student = rec.value(0).toString(),
            uid = rec.value(1).toString(),
            issued = rec.value(2).toString(),
            returned = rec.value(3).toString();

    if(query2.exec("SELECT NAME FROM allBooks WHERE UID = " + uid))
        uid = query2.record().value(0).toString();
    else
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Oops:", query2.lastError().text());

    if(returned == "Not yet returned")
        list << student + " issued " + uid + " on " + issued + " which is not returned yet";
    else
        list << student + " issued " + uid + " on " + issued + " and returned it on " + returned;
}

if(list.size() == 0)
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this, "Well...", "It seems that no book is issued");
    valid = false;
}
else
{
    model->setStringList(list);

    ui->listView->setModel(model);
}
```

The essence of the loop is that I have the uid of the book. I want to know the name of the book whose uid i have. But I dont know how to go about that.
The problem is, in the output the book name is not shown and neither any error. Both tables are in the same database. How can i access allBooks tables in the loop without affecting query1?

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry for so many doubts, but after solving this one bug, I may boast about making a complete minimal project.

Comment: You could share your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call a function like `query2.next()` to go to the first returned record.

Anyway, it would be easier to let the database join the tables together:

```
SELECT *
FROM log
JOIN allBooks USING (UID);
```